# Represent a directory as an object

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm building a tool that makes directories and renders `erb` files that live in a nested file structure.

For example take a file structure like this:

```
tmp
├── gem
│   ├── another_dir
│   │   └── bar.erb
│   ├── baz.erb
│   └── some_dir
│       └── foo.erb
├── gli
│   └── some_dir
│       └── foo.erb
├── methadone
│   └── some_dir
│       ├── foo.erb
│
```

My project would talk about this structure like this:

- there's a real directory called `tmp`
- inside it there are three real directories called: `gem`, `gli`, and `methadone`
- but in my project those would be called three "templates" called: `gem`, `gli`, and `methadone` (or maybe I should start calling them skeletons? Because the contain "template files"?)
- my idea is to "render the `gem` template"

  - what that really would mean is "render all the `erb` templates inside the `gem` directory"

For now, I think an important base object is a `Dir` object.

However, when I looked at the `Dir` object in ruby it didn't seem to give me the functionality I was expecting.

For example, I'd expect to be able to ask a directory:

- What is your name?
- What is your absolute path?
- What are all the paths recursively inside you?
- What are all the directories inside you?
- What are all the files inside?

I was surprised that an instance of the `Dir` class doesn't seem to respond to any of these messages.

Instead, it seems like this functionality is built into various class methods of the `File`, `Find`, and `Dir` class.

So I built my own `SomeDir` class:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'find'

class SomeDir
  include FileUtils
  attr_reader :path
  def initialize path
    @path = File.expand_path(path)
    mkdir_p path
  end

  def name
    File.basename path
  end

  def find
    Find.find(path).to_a
  end

  def dirs
    Dir.glob(path + "/**/*/")
  end

  def files
    Dir.glob(path + "/**/*")
  end
end
```

But it seems weird to me that I'm including all this functionality from say the `File` or `Find` class and I'm not inheriting from any classes.

Am I reinventing the wheel or missing the point of a how a directory should be represented as an object in ruby?
Should I be inheriting from the `Dir`, `File`, or `Find` class?

Comment: The Ruby core doesn't really have a representation for this. Maybe there's a gem that does what you want, or if not, there's an opportunity to make one if you're feeling inspired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, File and Dir have very few instance methods. The functionality is usually provided by class methods with a String (=filename) parameter. It makes it hard to inherit from File or Dir.

[Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) has many more instance methods, and defining :

```
class SomeDir < Pathname
end
```

will help you, at least for a few methods.

As a bonus, many Pathname methods return a Pathname or a Pathname Array, so it's easier to chain methods and use `select` or `reject`. With File or Dir, if you get a filename as answer, it's a String and you need to use yet another class method on it.